# pipenv install psycopg2>=2.7 --no-binary psycopg2

Tags: pip, pipenv

I have been using pipenv during development, however in prod i need to use pips `requirements.txt`

I incorporate dumping the pipenv to a requirements.txt file using the command:

```
   $ pipenv lock -r > requirements-new.txt;
```

All is well and good until i need `psycopg2>=2.7 --no-binary psycopg2` to appear in my requirements.txt.

How can I adjust pipenv to specify `--no-binary` on dumping to requirements.txt?

I've tried (but it's not working):

```
export PIP_NO_BINARY=:psycopg2: && pipenv install psycopg2==2.7
```

As a temporary measure I'm using:

```
    pipenv lock -r > requirements-new.txt;
    PSYCOPG_VERSION=$(sed -n -e 's/^.*psycopg2-binary==//p' requirements-new.txt);
    sed -i "s|psycopg2-binary==$PSYCOPG_VERSION|psycopg2==$PSYCOPG_VERSION --no-binary psycopg2|" requirements-new.txt;
```

but there must be a better way?

Answer (score 1):

pipenv respects any PIP variable and hence supports most of the pip options through `PIP_`.

I think your mistake is specifying colons around `psycopg2`. Colons are required for special values as ":any:" and ":none:". For regular packages, just list their names, comma-separated.

From: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-no-binary

> --no-binary
>
> Do not use binary packages. Can be supplied multiple times, and each time adds to the existing value.
>   Accepts either :all: to disable all binary packages, :none: to empty
>   the set, or one or more package names with commas between them. Note
>   that some packages are tricky to compile and may fail to install when
>   this option is used on them.